# How can i access to my formControl which is injected in my component?

Tags: angular, angular-content-projection

I have parent component. Inside it i am projecting a input.

```
<app-form-field>
  <input #input [id]="autoCompleteSearchInput" type="text" autoComplete="off"
   class='input-underline search-bar idented-text' [placeholder]="placeholder" 
   [formControl]="search" />
</app-form-field>
```

So i am having this control

```
[formControl]="search"
```

now i can't find a way to access to the content injected formControl from my AppFormFieldComponent.

I tried with
**HTML**

```
   <ng-content select=".input-underline"></ng-content>
```

**TS**

```
 @ContentChild(FormControlName, {static: false}) formControl: FormControlName;

ngAfterContentInit() {
  console.log(this.formControl);
}
```

but it gives me undefined.

How can i acess this form control so i can know what is typed inside input from my component ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `[formControl]` so you should use `FormControlDirective` in your `@ContentChild`:

```js
@ContentChild(FormControlDirective, {static: false})
formControl?: FormControlDirective;

ngAfterContentInit() {
  console.log(this.formControl);
}
```

Comment: Tahnk you for your feedback. But when i try in ngAfterContentInit to get the value through valuechanges - i don't get emitted values that i neter in my input. this.formControl.valueChanges.subscribe(x => {
      console.log('chiplist', x);
    })

Comment: How can i access to the value ?

Comment: this.formControl.control.value